# NFS clients seeing stale state

Tags: linux, redhat, nfs, rhel6

I have a server exporting partition as:

```
/data/foo     *.example.com(rw,sync,all_squash,anonuid=502,anongid=502,subtree_check)
```

... and client mounting it as:

```
myhost:/data/foo     /home/myuser/foo  nfs     auto,soft,intr,timeo=60       0    0
```

Client has a process that moves some files from directory called `in` to `error`, and server has a process that moves them back to `in`.

For some reason oftentimes client does not see up to date state. The lag is long enough that you can notice it on manually executing commands in the shell.

```
$ mv in/foo.txt error/foo.txt
mv: `in/foo.txt' and `error/foo.txt' are the same file
```

But that file is not in `error` anymore:

```
$ ls error/foo.txt
"No such file or directory"
```

Let's try removing:

```
$ rm error/foo.txt
rm: cannot remove `error/foo.txt': No such file or directory
```

Well, but now you *can* actually move the file.

Other times I may run into this curiosity:

```
$ mv in/foo.txt error/foo.txt; find . | grep foo
mv: cannot stat `in/foo.txt': No such file or directory
./in/foo.txt
```

What's going on here? How can I fixx it?

Comment: Are server and client clocks both NTP sync'ed?

Comment: @MadHatter Yes, both have NTP running. Manual check shows they are in sync too.

Comment: Scratch that hypothesis.